# Define a simple discrete probability distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I know the command: ProbabilityDistribution

I look at the detail of it, it seems a little troublesome.

For a very simple situation:

```
  n:       0        1       2
p(x=n)   0.3      0.4     0.3
```

how to define this a simple discrete probability distribution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can first define a piecewise function

```
piece[x_] := Piecewise[{{0.3, x == 0}, {0.4, x == 1}, {0.3, x == 2}}]
```

and feed it to `ProbabilityDistribution`

```
f = ProbabilityDistribution[piece[x], {x, 0, 2, 1}]
```

[image]

Its `PDF[f, x]`

[image]

and `CDF[f, x]`

[image]

You can plot it with

```
DiscretePlot[piece[x], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}]
```

or

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[f][x], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}]
```

[image]

```
Mean[f]
```

> 1.

which is

```
Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] f]
```

> 1.

Also

```
Variance[f]
```

> 0.6

or

```
Probability[x <= 1, x \[Distributed] f]
```

> 0.7

etc.

---

Alternatively you can use `EmpiricalDistribution` to do the same:

```
emp = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.3, 0.4, 0.3} -> {0, 1, 2}]

DiscretePlot[PDF[emp][x], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}]
```

> like previously

```
Plot[CDF[emp][x], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

etc.

Comment: Command `EmpiricalDistribution`      It is just what I need.

Comment: It's a bit frustrating that Mathematica doesn't have a native `DiscreteDistribution`

Comment: `EmpiricalDistribution` seems to be the same as `DiscreteDistribution`